# Unable to handle download pop up in edge chromium browser in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to handle the edge chromium browser download popup scenario but so far no luck. Since the popup is neither a window popup nor a browser popup I am not sure how to handle it.

Screenshot of how the download prompt looks like:
[image]

I have tried to use tab to reach to the save button. But it is not working since the active elements are changing dynamically. I have tried below edge browser capability but it is not working.

```js
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
```

Can someone please suggest a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Without being able to see the website myself (can you share it?) it's probably an iframe. If so, you'll have to use switchTo

Comment: The screenshot isn't included, please edit your question and fix that. Maybe you want to upload the image first to any public URL before.

Comment: Hi @nilsandrey, I have added link for the screenshot.